# Is it possible that multithreads extract global variables that are streamed from an outside source?

Tags: python, python-3.x, streaming, python-multithreading

I am not sure how multithread works in Python so that's why I am asking this question. I'd appreciate if there are examples of codes about this problem. The problem is as follows:

Say I have 4 arrays, X1, X2, X3 and X4. X1 through X4 are data live-streamed to python from an outside source. They get updated for every second.

Then I have 4 threads:

Th1 handling array X1, Th2 handling X2,... and Th4 handling X4 respectively.

What thread I does is the following:

Whenever a special pattern appears in Xi, return a signal back to the outside source. This thread i only stops when the live stream of array Xi is terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multithreading and multiprocessing allow you to perform tasks in parallel. You could use them to loop through your 4 arrays in parallel. However, you would need a different library to transmit the data you are using.

Comment: Which one(multithreading or multiprocessing) is more preferable? I heard that one is more computationally expensive than another. Also, do you happen to know what library is the best to handle a stream of time series data? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Multiprocessing is more computationally expensive since it can use multiple processors whereas multithreading cannot. I don't know what library you would use for that. Maybe some sort of scraper like scrapy if the data is coming from online?